# EF4: First SaveChanges to remote server takes ~15 min

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a small app, that writes some basic data to sql server (2019) on remote server.

When trying to save the first record SaveChanges is hanging for ~15 minutes, then it succeeds and continue writing the next record with no delay.

In this code I try to write single value to configuration table (columns: name, value)

```
internal static bool Insert(string Name, string value)
        {
            dbConfTable currentObj = null;

            using (myDBEntities db = new myDBEntities(ConnectionString))
            {

                dbConfTable currentObj = db.Configurations.Create();

                currentObj.Value = value;
                currentObj.Name = Name;

                db.Configurations.Add(currentObj);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Things I tried:

- Pre-generate the view - did not help
- SaveChanges once with no changes - Save with no changes succeeded, EFhangs
- Write directly to sql using SqlCommand and then accessing using EF- SqlCommand succeeded, EF hangs
- Write to local sql server - works correctly

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using EF4? EF6 has been out for 5+ years.

Comment: Is this a _database-first_ (EDMX) project, or _code-first_? Are you using EF Migrations? What is the nature of the remote SQL Server (is it adequately provisioned with enough RAM? Is it a `LocalDb` database? What SKU is it running?)

Comment: EF4 - old and dinosaur code with to much dependencies to upgrade.
this is _database first_ project

Comment: Can you see when the changes are actually written on the remote server, i.e. when the insert statement is executed? Could MSDTC play a role here?